# Desktop installation

Tags: software-installation

*I am installing lxqt desktop in termux ubuntu and papirus-icon theme is not completing setup.I tried Ctrl+c to interupt and now system wont install  anything else.

It says run dpkg --configure -a but if i run it, does not work either**

Comment: You've provided no release details; and a copy/paste of your actual package(s) & error messages might also help people to understand your issue(s).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.